# Reading multiple bytes in Arduino sent using Pyserial

Tags: arduino, byte, python-3.8, pyserial, arduino-nano

I'm constantly sending structs of int64  via Pyserial with:

```
with serial.Serial(port='COM4', baudrate=115200, timeout=.1) as arduino:    
        value = write_read(struct.pack(">q", int_array[1][i])) #this sends signed int.64 in bytes
        print(value)
```

the struct.pack has this shape, for example:

```
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xef'
```

and the function write_read consists of:

```
def write_read(x):
    arduino.write((x))
    data = arduino.readline()
    #the idea is to receive an ACK from the Arduino after 8 bytes (the full 
    #number)
    return data
```

The code I'm trying to develop in arduino is the following:

```
void loop() {
// send data only when you receive data:
if (Serial.available() \> 0) {
// read the incoming byte:
incomingByte = Serial.read();

    //read 8 bytes and create the result
    r= function_to_read_8_last_bytes // or similar
    
    // say what you got:
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.printlesultn(r, DEC);
    Serial.write("ACK");
}
}
```

I'm very curious how I could do a robust "read 8 bytes" function.
Should I add some especial character in the Python part to indentify when it ends one value?

Thanks! I'll appreciate any help :)

Comment: This is a very common problem, if this can reassure you. Consider that the serial communication was meant to work with ASCII encoding, where you have special encodings to signal start-end of message, and you don't need the whole 256 symbols to write a message. When sending raw bytes you *might* use headers (a particular sequence) to notify start/end, but there is **no** guarantee that such pattern won't appear in your data.

Comment: If you are willing to lose some packets you can create an header and a closing sequence that contains a CRC or parity, which then you check on ARDUINO's side. If the header was just data you won't get a correct CRC, and you discard the whole packet.

Comment: I see. Seemed like a general problem yes.
Just to simplify it: how could I transform the 8 bytes, into the signed int? Should I use this operator: << ?? 
thanks

Comment: Are we talking about python or C?

Comment: In Arduino (C). I receive the bytes one by one - and the thing is to use them to build the signed int32

Comment: Consider data might come slower than arduino can read. Even at 115200. When Serial.available() returns > 0, wait 1 ms and recheck that a next Serial.available() returns 8. Or read each byte bytes into an int until you do not get 0 .. 255, but -1 (no more data).

Comment: I would use a union rather than the << operator, it's way more neat and there is no need to mask/cast things. I wrote an answer, let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Given the discussion in the comments, it's hard to receive a stream of bytes and be sure that the receiver is completely synchronized. However let's make some assumptions to ease the problem:

1. The serial buffer is empty when you connect your laptop to Arduino. This ensures you won't receive spurious data with no meaning. I had this problem happens a lot when the serial connection was ended abruptly by any cause.
2. You are not constantly sending bytes, Arduino has time to process them until the start of the new sequence.
3. You only send this data, so there is no need to create a higher level protocol on top of it. Bare in mind that the serial communication is almost just an hardware stack, you receive bytes with no headers.

For assumption 1 you can write a simple piece of code to consume all the spurious bytes in the serial buffer as soon as your main starts from Arudino, so this will be done everytime you connect the serial (as this is also where the power supply comes from). Something like this:

```
void serialFlush(){
  while(Serial.available() > 0) {
    char t = Serial.read();
  }
}
```

You can send a "READY" signal back to the Python interface, so that the program knows you are ready to receive data.

Going on with the solution you can implement an easy CRC in python, an additional byte which contains a XOR of all the previous bytes, and you check that in Arduino upon reception complete.

```
def xor_reduce_long_int(li):
    res = 0;
    for i in range(8):
         
        mask = (0xFF)<<(i*8)
        print(hex(mask))
        masked = (li&mask)>>(i*8)
        res ^= masked
       
    return res

with serial.Serial(port='COM4', baudrate=115200, timeout=.1) as arduino:    
        crc=xor_reduce_long_int(int_array[1][i])
        value = write_read(struct.pack(">qc", int_array[1][i],crc)) #this sends signed int.64 in bytes
        print(value)
```

And with Arduino I would read 8 bytes when they are available and put them into an unsigned char buffer. I would then define a union that alias such buffer to interpret it as long long int.

```
typedef struct long_int_CRC
{
    union
    {
        unsigned char bytes[8];
        long int data;
    };
    unsigned char CRC; 
}data_T;

// .. Later in main

data_T = received_data;

int received_bytes=0
unsigned char  my_CRC = 0;
unsigned char  rec_byte= 0;
while( received_bytes < 8 )
{
    if(Serial.available() )
    {
        // Get the byte
        rec_byte = Serial.read()

        // Store the byte and calc CRC
        received_data.bytes[received_bytes] = rec_byte;
        my_CRC ^= rec_byte;

        // Increment counter for next byte
        received_bytes++;
    }
}

// Reception complete, check CRC
unsigned char rec_CRC;

if(Serial.available() )
{
    rec_CRC = Serial.read()
}

if( my_CRC != rec_CRC ) 
{
   // Something was wrong! 
}

// Now access your data as a long int
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.printlesultn(received_data.data, DEC);
    Serial.write("ACK");
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. 
I'm trying it and I have this problem at the line "crc=reduce(lambda x, y:x^y, int_array64[1][i])":

TypeError: reduce() arg 2 must support iteration

Comment: Yeah I made a typo, but I hope you get the spirit of my answer and don't just copy paste it. Do you understand what's wrong? It should be reducing the whole array. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't totally get what does write_read(struct.pack(">qc", int_array[1][i],crc)). How will the function send "x" when "x=int_array,crc". Shouldn't the crc send afterwards or something? Should I modify the function write_read or change it for simple arduino.write? Thank you very much anyways.

Comment: Hi @user20035360 I added the correct function to calculate the CRC (I was treating the integer as an array, which is wrong). I calculate the CRC masking it. The function sends x and the crc, the arduino code acts accordingly to decode first the number, then the crc.